# How to delete a record from mysql which are having the given id

Tags: php, mysql

Now i have the table like

```
--------------------------
merge_id  |  merge_combo |
--------------------------
A1        |   25,9       |
A2        |   25,21      |
A3        |   2,5,15     |
A4        |   2,9,5      |
A5        |   12,19,2    |
A6        |   2,1        |
--------------------------
```

for example now if i pass the value 9, then it should check the merge_combo and delete the rows which are having 9 (A1,A4 this two having 9)

Comment: is merge combo varchar?

Comment: Normalize your tables, else you need to query using LIKE and then removing manually from each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `find_in_set()`:

```
delete from tbl
    where find_in_set(9, merge_combo) > 0;
```

The bigger issue is that you are storing *numbers* in a string for a list.  SQL has this great data structure for storing lists -- it is called a table.  In this case, you want a junction table, with one row per `merge_id` and combo item.

Comment: what it actually do ?  >0

Comment: @user3419304 please check once [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE from your_table where FIND_IN_SET(9, merge_combo) or merge_combo IN(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following qry

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE merge_combo LIKE '%,9,%' OR merge_combo LIKE '9,%' OR merge_combo LIKE '%,9' OR merge_combo = '9';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Find_In_Set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
delete from your_table where FIND_IN_SET(@val, merge_combo)
```

> [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
>
> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
>   first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
>   SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.
>   Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.
>   Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work
>   properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE FIND_IN_SET("9",merge_combo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** create a complex SQL query with `LIKE`.If you have a bad db design your app will be bad too.

Instead normalize your database that comes up even against the 1NF. Try to break `merge_combo` to `merge_comboA` and `merge_comboB` and `merge_comboC` if you know that you will have to untill 3 combo values or for the best implementation create a separate table with composite keys (this way you will avoid Null values)

**PS** : use the queries proposed only if you can't change your database (e.g. an academic exercise to test your knoweledge on queries)

Answer (score 0):

Connection:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost', 'admin_user', 'Paradise1191', 'admin_db');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Select & Delete:

```
$var = "Your Result";
$array = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $this_id = $row['merge_id'];
    $var1 = $row['merge_combo'];
    $array = explode(",",$var1 );
    if (in_array($var, $people)) {

    $query = "DELETE FROM `TABLE` WHERE `merge_id` = '$this_id'";
    $mysqli->query($query);        

    }

}
$result->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this following query:

```
DELETE FROM merge WHERE merge_combo LIKE '% 9 %';
```